# No member named 'get_mapping_handle' in 'boost::interprocess::basic_managed_shared_memory

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile some boost code but am getting the following error

This is a simplified version of the code

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
using namespace boost::interprocess;
int main()
{
      managed_shared_memory shmem(create_only, "MySharedMemory", sizeof(TransferData));
      mapped_region region(shmem, read_write);
}
```

But I get this issue

```
In file included from holster/src/main.cc:6:
In file included from external/boost/boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp:26:
In file included from external/boost/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_open_or_create_impl.hpp:26:
external/boost/boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp:594:39: error: no member named 'get_mapping_handle' in 'boost::interprocess::basic_managed_shared_memory<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, int, unsigned int, 0>, 0>, iset_index>'
   mapping_handle_t map_hnd = mapping.get_mapping_handle();
                              ~~~~~~~ ^
holster/src/main.cc:96:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'boost::interprocess::mapped_region::mapped_region<boost::interprocess::basic_managed_shared_memory<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, int, unsigned int, 0>, 0>, iset_index> >' requested here
      mapped_region region(shmem, read_write, 1000);
                    ^
In file included from holster/src/main.cc:6:
In file included from external/boost/boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp:26:
In file included from external/boost/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_open_or_create_impl.hpp:26:
external/boost/boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp:702:32: error: no member named 'get_mapping_handle' in 'boost::interprocess::basic_managed_shared_memory<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, int, unsigned int, 0>, 0>, iset_index>'
                     , mapping.get_mapping_handle().handle
                       ~~~~~~~ ^
```

This is the version of boost I am using

```
Version: 1.71.0.0ubuntu2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an excellent minimized example.

It shows clearly what you're doing wrong. You're using a mapped region on a managed segment. That's not what they're for, or even supported:

[image]

[Also:](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.shared_memory_mapping_shared_memory_segments)

> Once created or opened, a process just has to map the shared memory object in the process' address space. The user can map the whole shared memory or just part of it. The mapping process is done using the ***mapped_region*** class. The class represents a memory region that has been mapped from a shared memory or from other devices that have also mapping capabilities (for example, files). A mapped_region can be created from any memory_mappable object and as you might imagine, shared_memory_object is a memory_mappable object [...]

I can't find a definitive list, but as far as I know here's the list of models that satisfy the `memory_mappable` requirements:

- `boost::interprocess::file_mapping`
- `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object`
- `boost::interprocess::xsi_shared_memory`

> Besides, you're specifying `sizeof(TransferData)` for the segment and that's not gonna work in the first place: [Why does boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory throw a boost::interprocess_exception upon construction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62748438/why-does-boostinterprocessmanaged-shared-memory-throw-a-boostinterprocess/62759367#62759367)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks so much :-)